# How to clear python interpreter screen

Tags: python, console

I've tried many ways to clear python interpreter screen like:

```
import os
os.system("cls")
```

but couldn't do so, please tell me how to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> import os
>>> os.system("cls")
```

Should work on windows.

---

If you are using Linux, you might use `clear` instead of `cls`.

Comment: i just tried it again on my windows os and it gives me a `0` value , is this window specific ?

Comment: I'm using Windows, and i think i have some environment variables messed up, i'v installed cocos 2d a few days earlier and it require to add some environment variables. after that i'm unable to clear console both on c++(visual studio) and python. Have you anything on mind  ??????

Answer (score 2):

`os.system("cls")` will work only on windows machine. If you are UNIX user, do:

- Using escape sequence:

  ```
  print(chr(27) + "[2J")
  ```
- Alternatively, if you are Unix user (not Windows), you may also do:

  ```
  import sys
  sys.stderr.write("\x1b[2J\x1b[H")
  # Code for clear screen in UNIX machines
  ```

Comment: Dude i tried many on my xp os but none worked including the one mentioned here , maybe they are os specific as agreed by uriel eli too

Comment: sys.stderr.write("\x1b[2J\x1b[H") for the best answer in clearing the entire screen in Linux/UNIX without any white space or 0 response.